# Cause of `fork: retry: No child processes`

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, fork

When I run a certain commercial build flow in OpenSuse, I encounter the following error:

```
fork: retry: No child processes
```

I encounter this error at various locations in the flow that corresponds with different executables, so I believe that the tool itself is not the problem.   However, I run several instances (up to 16) of this build flow at the same time.  The build is dispatched to different servers according to load, so sometimes a few builds run on the same machine.  I suspect that the server load has somehow to do with this, but I cannot figure out exactly how.

I suspect that the error message corresponds with the `EAGAIN` error of `fork`. The `fork` manual gives several potential causes for this error:

1. the `RLIMIT_NPROC` soft resource limit (set via `setrlimit(2)`), which limits the number of processes and threads for a real user ID, was reached
2. the kernel's system-wide limit on the number of processes and threads, `/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max`, was reached (see `proc(5)`)
3. the maximum number of PIDs, `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max`, was reached

I believe none of these are satisfied, because

1. `ulimit -a` reports unlimited as the maximum number of user processes.
2. `/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max` is set to 1031129. I monitor the number of lines in `ps auxH`, which should be the number of threads (plus the header line that ps outputs I guess), at a 1-second granularity, but it never gets higher than 917.
3. `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` is set to 32768. I monitor the number of processes using `ps aux`, but it never gets higher than 726.

I believe I read somewhere that there is also a possibility that the kernel ran out of other (memory?) resources.  How can I check that?  Or is something else wrong in my line of reasoning?

The output form `ulimit -a` is:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 515564
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 5120
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: are you starting threads using `fork` only? Or using pthreads?

Comment: More probably than running out of processes, the system might run out of stack space (when using threads) or file descriptors

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I don't know whether threads are started using fork or pthreads. Given the complexity of the tool, I guess it uses a combination of both. I guess I could use strace to determine what is used.I created a simple C application that counts how many forks it can do, and it reaches 12272 processes before it fails.

Comment: I monitor the amount of free memory while I run the build flow (using the Linux `free` command), and there is still about 63 GB available (it's a server with about 126 GB DRAM). I would say that rules out lack of stack space. I suppose file descriptors are kept in kernel space, which is limited. According to `/proc/sys/fs/file-nr`, at most 14144 file descriptors are in use. According to `/proc/sys/fs/file-max`, I cannot use more than 13164302 of them, which is sufficient. I guess kernel space runs out before that. Do you have any idea whether or how I can see the amount of kernel space left?

Comment: can you post an output of `ulimit -a` so we can see *all* limits set? BTW *Stack space* is a per-user limit, not a general one. I would assume what you're hitting is a user limit - The kernel ones are normally very generous.

Comment: I added the output to the question.

Comment: `ECHILD` is not in the error list for `fork`. So I guess it comes from `waitpid`. Can you run  it under `strace`?

Comment: Stack size 8 M *could* be tight, depending on number of threads running. Maybe you could try and lift this a bit?

Comment: @fukanchik, that's correct. However, the `jobs.c:make_child()` 
implementation of at least _bash-4.2_ attempts to correctively reap children after encountering EAGAIN, but it does not safely preserve errno while doing so.  The reaping ends with ECHLD, of course, and _bash_ erroneously reports that as the `fork()` failure.  Corrected in at least _bash-4.4_.  More to the point, this does suggest that the OP is hitting what Linux documents as a [`fork()` memory error condition reported as EAGAIN](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it is obvious, but is the ulimit -a output for user that is running this build flow? Example output from one of my servers:

```
[root@server]# cat /etc/security/limits.d/20-nproc.conf
# Default limit for number of user's processes to prevent
# accidental fork bombs.
# See rhbz #432903 for reasoning.
*          soft    nproc     4096
root       soft    nproc     unlimited
```

Usually unlimited nr of processes is left only for root in order not to run in a fork bomb. Here all other users except root will have a limit.

Also, I see a limit on nr of open files. For a user you can check this with `lsof -u <user>| wc -l`

Comment: not the case here but in mine some process was hoarding RAM - hope it helps